# Unreadable file

Tags: c++, file-structure

I am using a code from online on file structures. I am facing a hard time to solve the problem of being able to read what I write into the file.[This is how the data entered is getting stored in the file.

How to make it readable?

[image]

code:

```
void write_student() {
  student st;
  int nu, fla = 0;
  ofstream outFile;
  outFile.open("stu1.txt", ios::app);
  cout << "Enter roll number";
  cin >> nu;
  cout << "Checking for constraint violation......";
  fla = pkey(nu);
  if (fla == 0) {
    st.getdata();
    outFile.write((char *)&st, sizeof(student));
    outFile.open("stu1.txt", ios::app);
    outFile.close();
    cout << "\n\nStudent record Has Been Created ";
    cin.ignore();
  } else
    cout << "\n\nPRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT VIOLATED\n";
  getch();
}
void student::getdata() {
  cout << "\nConfirm The roll number of student ";
  cin >> rollno;
  cin.ignore();
  cout << "\n\nEnter The Name of student ";
  cin >> name;
  cin.ignore();
  cout << "\nEnter The marks in Cryptography out of 100      : ";
  cin >> p_marks;
  cin.ignore();
  cout << "\nEnter The marks in File Structure out of 100    : ";
  cin >> c_marks;
  cin.ignore();
  cout << "\nEnter The marks in Software Testing out of 100  : ";
  cin >> m_marks;
  cin.ignore();
  cout << "\nEnter The marks in Operating System out of 100  : ";
  cin >> e_marks;
  cin.ignore();
  cout << "\nEnter The marks in Python out of 100            : ";
  cin >> cs_marks;
  cin.ignore();
}
```

This is a part of the code where marks of a student is added. I want to be able to read the content of stu1.txt. Thanks for the help!!

My `student` class is defined as

```
class student 
{ 
    int rollno; 
    char name[50]; 
    int p_marks, c_marks, m_marks, e_marks, cs_marks; 
    float per; 
    char grade; 
    void calculate();

    public: 
    void getdata(); 
    void getdata1(); 
    void showdata();    
    void show_tabular(); 
    int retrollno(); 
};
```

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I also recommend [this SO question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And to nag a little, please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please include example input/output too.

Comment: Looks pretty much readable for me. What do you expect to get?

Comment: Why dont you define a method on your student which builds a human readable string (a la java's `toString`) and write that to the file. If you write the struct directly it will not make much sense viewed as text.

Comment: An example would be a name say paul and the score in different subjects in the list. I want to be able to read what I give as the input and if you see the image it is not exactly a readable format.

Comment: As a *guess* about what's going on: The `student` class contain members that can't be written as raw data. For example, a `std::string` object is really nothing more than a *pointer* and a size (it's a little more complicated than that, but to keep it simple). Pointers on a modern protected virtual-memory system are specific to one process only. If you save a pointer, that pointer is invalid in all other process attempting to read it, even if the process is running the same program.

Comment: As for a possible way to solve your problem, I suggest you do some research about [*serialization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).

Comment: Without seeing how student is defined all we can do is guess.  You're writing it as binary data though which is generally not what you want to do if you want a readable file. As @Someprogrammerdude said, you may even be writing things not meant to be written to and read from files.

Comment: class student
{
 int rollno;
 char name[50];
 int p_marks, c_marks, m_marks, e_marks, cs_marks;
 float per;
 char grade;
 void calculate(); 
public:
 void getdata(); 
 void getdata1();
 void showdata(); 
 void show_tabular();
 int retrollno();
}; This is the student class.

Comment: @SkandaBharadwaj what is the format you expect to see in the file? Whatever it is, that wont just happen by accident, you will need to define that format in code.

Comment: @PaulRooney I want to see the content in readable form i.e, the input I give should reflect in that file in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing student completely as binary data and reading it from an ASCII file.

A simple solution would be to implement a `writeToFile` function in the student class:

```
class student 
{ 
    int rollno; 
    char name[50]; 
    int p_marks, c_marks, m_marks, e_marks, cs_marks; 
    float per; 
    char grade; 
    void calculate();

    public: 
    void getdata(); 
    void getdata1(); 
    void showdata();    

    void write(std::ofstream& file); //<--- implement writing function

    void show_tabular(); 
    int retrollno(); 
}; 

void student::write(std::ofstream& file){
    if(!file.is_open())
        return;
    file << "Name    : " << std::string(name) << "\n";
    file << "Roll no.: " << rollno << "\n";

    file << "Marks   : " << "\n";
    file << "\tp: " << p_marks "\n";  
    file << "\tp: " << c_marks << "\n";  
    file << "\tp: " << m_marks << "\n";  
    file << "\tp: " << e_marks << "\n";  
    file << "\tp: " << cs_marks << "\n"; 

    file << "Per.   : " << per << "\n";
    file << "Grade  : " << grade<< "\n";
}
```

But watch out for the name char array. If there is no string termination (\0), it will write out garbage after the name (assuming the name is shorter than 50 chars).